# Run Time error - earn for money

Tags: java

I tried to solve the UVA problem Earn For Money ID: 12614
on my IDE I get a correct answer for all cases 
but when I submitted on the uva online judge I get a run time error

there is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main{

/**
 * UVAonlineJudge
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main e = new Main();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    final int T = scan.nextInt();
    for(int i=0 ; i < T ; i++){
         int N = scan.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[N];
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        int j = 0;
        for(String num : line.split(" ")){
            array[j] = Integer.parseInt(num);
            j++;
        }
        int m= i+1;
        System.out.println("Case "+ m + ": " + e.getMax(array));

    }
    scan.close();
}
int getMax(int[] array){
    int first_max = array[0];
    for(int i=1 ; i < array.length ; i++){
        if(array[i] >first_max){
            first_max = array[i];
        }
    }
    return first_max;
}



}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Please narrow down your problem to the exact line where you get the error.

Comment: In addition to bot suggestion I want to say  in this case you can add the expected input here so that we can guess from where the runtime exception occured

Comment: the online judge give me a Runtime error .. I don't know where is the problem exactly

Comment: @Sunny check out the answer , it might solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will be getting

`Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException`

**NoSuchElementException** is thrown by the **nextElement()** method of an Enumeration to indicate that there are no more elements in the enumeration.

Check here for more on  [No Such Element Exception](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-util-nosuchelementexception-how-to-solve-nosuchelementexception/)

So intead of directly using `scan.nextInt()` , first use `hasNextInt()` to check wheather an element is present or not

I'll also suggest you to use **BufferedReader Class** to take *inputs*.

Comment: where I can use the BufferedReader Class ?

Comment: Replace your Scanner class code to take input with BufferedReader ,
Check here [how to take input with BufferedReader](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/UsingBufferedReadertoreadinputnumberfromuser.htm)